# Was installing Ubuntu and I pressed quit in between and now am stuck in some command line

Tags: ubuntu-core, usb-installation

I was trying to install Ubuntu and in on the screen where you decide partitions .I clicked on quit and now I am stuck on some command line and nothing is happening. 
pls help

Comment: I tried installing ubuntu Desktop 18.04 LTS. if this helps

Comment: didn't know much about that , but forced shut down worked back then .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reboot the PC holding down the hardware on/off button, and try the installation again.

If you don't have any data on the HD you need, you can let the installer automatically partition the HD next time.